# Excel COUNTIF with link to another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to get the count of records from a sheet in a different workbook. I'm using the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF('C:\Path\To\File\[WORK1.xlsm]SheetName'!$A:$A,"*")-1
```

`NOTE: The file is an xlsM. It has a header row, that's why I'm subtracting 1`

If I have the WORK1.XLSM file open at the same time as my 'Summary' workbook, then the numbers populate and are correct. Once I close WORK1, I get `#VALUE` in the cell.

So 2 questions:

1. Is there a reason this won't work?
2. Is there a better way to write this?

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNTIF` doesn't work with closed workbooks, looks like you can use COUNTA, i.e.

`=COUNTA('C:\Path\To\File\[WORK1.xlsm]SheetName'!$A:$A)-1`